# Background-change works only in chrome + $.preload doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I made a script to change background images every 8 seconds. Everything works fine in chrome, but in other browsers it doesn't. (Tested on Safari, Edge, IE 9 - 11 and Mozilla). I also have the jQuery preload plugin, but it actually doesn't preload the images. The console doesn't show me any errors, so I don't know why it doesn't work.
Code:

```
var c = 1,  
    nimg = $('header .background .img').attr('data-bg'),
    bgpath = $('header .background .img').css('background').match(/"(.*)"/),
    imgpath,
    imgs = [],
    startpath,
    startpoint,
    selector = 'header .background .content .text',
    time = 8000;
if (path[1] == 'diwerf') {
    startpath = '/'+path[1];
} else {
    startpath = '/templates';
};
startpoint = bgpath[1].search(startpath);
bgpath = bgpath[1].slice(startpoint);

for (var g = 1; g <= nimg; g++) {
    imgpath = bgpath.replace(/[0-9]/g, g);

    imgs.push(imgpath);
};

$.preload(imgs);

function removeText() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(selector).fadeOut('slow', function() {
            $(this).removeClass('animated').removeAttr('style');
        });
    }, time-600);
}

removeText();

setInterval(function() {
    if (c == nimg) {
        c = 0;
    };
    c++;
    bgpath = bgpath.replace(/[0-9]/g, c);
    $('header .background .img').css('background', 'url('+bgpath+') center center no-repeat');

    setTimeout(function() {
        $(selector+'-'+c).addClass('animated');
    }, 600);

    removeText();
}, time+100);
```

It doesn't do anything, not even adding the 'animated' class.

Here you can see the website: http://www.testing.dw-erfolg.eu/

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a shorthand CSS property, which is not guaranteed in all browsers.

```
bgpath = $('header .background .img').css('background').match(/"(.*)"/),
```

Instead you should use `.css('backgroundImage')`

Make sure you also change line 42:

```
$('header .background .img').css('backgroundImage', 'url('+bgpath+')');
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. Also, do you know why the $.preload doesn't work?

Comment: You had an error before that line, so it might cause the browser not to get to that part. Make the changes and check again.

Comment: It didn't work, but doesn't matter. I used something else.
Thanks anyway!